# Validation if the clickable value in the cell exist

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

On the web page there is a table. 
Behavior:
- if the event happens, the new line (raw) is added to the table and the first cell of this line is clickable;
- if the event does not happen, the new line is not added.

The negative (the event does not happen)auto test needs to validate that there is no raws except the headers in that table.

Could you please suggest what the best way is to do that?
I guess, if I create the method to click on that cell - the test will fail with the message that selenium can't find this cell to click....

Comment: You can wait until new line item is shown. Clickable? does the item has an 'a' tag? . negaive side - you can check the element is exist() and catch that exception to pass the scenario.

Comment: I need just to check the negative (positive is clear). "the element is exist() and catch that exception to pass the scenario" - could you please show the possible code in this case? thx!

Comment: see my answer below. The only down side is that your script will stop until the wait time. you can reduce the wait time whatever that fits your application/ scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Negative scenario - to check if element does not exists.

Use explicit wait to wait for element ( the side effect - the script will halt until the wait time)

```
try{
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("you element xpath or use any other locators"))));
    System.out.println("Element is visible - fail");
// you can add assert statement here.

}
catch(TimeoutException e)
{
    System.out.println("Element is not visible - Pass");
// you can add assert statement here.

}
```